# Glide.load desde request

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-glide

En mi aplicación android estoy utilizando la librería Glide para la carga de imágenes, pero necesito cargar imágenes que solo se obtienen con llamadas POST y un body determinado (no regresan con solo una URL).

Por ahora lo que hago es descargar las imágenes desde otro hilo y ya almacenadas las cargo con load(URI) pero es ineficiente, espero me puedan ayudar.

Gracias.

Comment: Lo que deseas es mostrar imágenes desde un servidor de internet? Si ese es el caso te recomendaría usar la Api Volley para peticiones desde Android con Php parseado a Json, te dejo un link: http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/02/android-volley-peticiones-http/

Comment: Gracias por responder...
Ya lo probé, Volley si provee un request especial para recibir imagenes, pero lo hace de la misma manera que Glide y Picasso (con una dirección URL), mi problema es que las imagenes de mi servidor solo las provee a partir de una petición POST con parametros.

Comment: Prueba con la solución de: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106527/glide-adding-header-to-request y nos cuentas

Answer (score 1):

Esto lo puedes lograr con AsyncTask, en doInBackground() realizas la obtencion de la imagen y cuando termine ejecuta onPostExecute() que es donde cargarías la url de la imagen mediante Glide.

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
           String urlPost = params[0];     
                //Obtiene urlImagen mediante POST.
                //retorna la url de la imagen obtenida.
                 return urlImagen;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String urlImagen) {
                if (!urlImagen.equals("")) {
                    //En base a la url obtenida carga la imagen por medio de Glide.
                };
            }
        }.execute();
```